# How can I perform migration of Cloud Datastore entities using Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I am currently performing the migration using a single machine which runs sequentially and reads the Entities from the namespaces which is painful for me. Is it possible to use Google Cloud Dataflow to perform the migration easier?

Comment: Hi Chandra, could you expand on your use case a bit?  Is this a one-time data migration between different Datastore schemas, or something else?

Comment: Hi @SamMcVeety sorry for the late reply, it is a one-time data migration within the Datastore, for ex., adding a new column to the Entity and transforming the data  from Entity to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [DatastoreIO](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/DatastoreIO) to manipulate the records and process them in parallel.

```
PCollection<Entity> entities = p.apply(
     Read.from(DatastoreIO.read()
         .withDataset(datasetId)
         .withQuery(query)
         .withHost(host)));
p.apply(<Your transform>)
p.apply(DatastoreIO.writeTo(dataset));
p.run();
```

As of Dataflow SDK for Java 1.2.0, support for querying and writing  Datastore [Entities in namespaces](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/v1.2.0/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/DatastoreIO.java#L93) has been added.